# differences between firmware, chipset and EPROM inside a computer

Tags: firmware, chipset, rom, eeprom

All chipset, EPROM and firmware in a computer seem to have some physical electronic components that contain codes for controlling the working flow of processor, RAM and other hardware peripherals, but I couldn't to find an obvious difference between them on Google. May you help me please?

Comment: A chipset is a hardware specification, firmware is software, and EPROM is actual hardware.  **Your question is not clear.**

Comment: I tried to ask the question using simple words of the English language. I don't know how it's not clear! Anyway, which part has issue? I try to clarify it.

Comment: Why are you trying to compare 3 entirely separate concepts?  Only the implemented chipset specification and EPROM actually has hardware associated with it.  The firmware is what programmed into the actual hardware.  Here is a good [question](http://superuser.com/questions/129070/difference-between-chipset-and-motherboard?rq=1) about firmware and chipsets.

Answer (score 3):

(From wikipedia:

[EPROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPROM)

> An EPROM (rarely EROM), or erasable programmable read only memory, is a type of memory chip that retains its data when its power supply is switched off. In other words, it is non-volatile. It is an array of floating-gate transistors individually programmed by an electronic device that supplies higher voltages than those normally used in digital circuits. Once programmed, an EPROM can be erased by exposing it to strong ultraviolet light source (such as from a mercury-vapor light). EPROMs are easily recognizable by the transparent fused quartz window in the top of the package, through which the silicon chip is visible, and which permits exposure to UV light during erasing.

[Chipset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chipset)

> In a computer system, a chipset is a set of electronic components in an integrated circuit that manages the data flow between the processor, memory and peripherals. It is usually found on the motherboard. Chipsets are usually designed to work with a specific family of microprocessors. Because it controls communications between the processor and external devices, the chipset plays a crucial role in determining system performance.

[Firmware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware)

> In electronic systems and computing, firmware is the combination of persistent memory and program code and data stored in it.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPROM) Typical examples of devices containing firmware are embedded systems (such as traffic lights, consumer appliances, and digital watches), computers, computer peripherals, mobile phones, and digital cameras. The firmware contained in these devices provides the control program for the device.

So in other words, a chipset could be a set of EPROM chips, and firmware is the software, or program(s), that runs contained on those chips.

Answer (score 1):

EEPROM is an older type of memory that is usually small but cheap. It is commonly used for storing settings and is not that common in modern computers.

Firmware is a type of software program, usually stored in a flash memory on the motherboard. The most obvious example is the BIOS, but other devices such as graphics cards and hard disks also have firmware of their own. Usually you don't see the firmware in any list of software on the computer, as it operates underneath Windows.

A chipset is the name given to the group of chips required to build a functional computer. These days it is typically a single chip, but in the past would have consisted of several, each with a unique function.

Comment: *"EEPROM is an older type of memory..."* -- Actually the question was about "EPROM" and not "EEPROM".  FYI Flash memory (as used in SSDs and USB flash drives) is a type of EEPROM.

Comment: All true. EEPROM generally refers to an older style of storage device though, rather than the flash memory chips used in SSDs. Of course in practice the technology is similar, but for example flash memory usually has a higher bad bit rate than EEPROM. EPROM is similar to EEPROM, but can't be erased electronically.

Answer (score -3):

**Firmware is not software**.
Firmware is the permanent code/program that runs the system.
It is a code that controls hardware and often serves by a system which has **software**.
In example an operating system installed on a hard drive AKA **software**.
This is why we differentiate between RAM and ROM.
RAM as we know is cached and dumped regularly in modern computer systems.
A firmware is generally stored in the ROM.
This is also often known as a kernel.

You're really looking at chronological layers of technology dating back to Bell Labs where the programming language of C was invented.
This is ultimately what was invented to progress beyond binary.

Look at the word.
E P ROM

My explanation is far from perfect but highly accurate compared to the previous. I've been out of school a couple years and after some review will soon go back so it's all still fuzzy.
ROMS are stored in solid state memory devices so resetting these massive networks of semiconductor switches requires a precision system of high controlled pulses OR the analog way which is to just bathe the EPROM with powerful UV light. 
1 switch = 1 byte
1 gbs = 2 billion bytes

Amazing when you see the size of your NAND flash that can hold 64gbs

Once the firmware is written it is obvious firm, and you won't be simply rewriting it without a special programming board and the necessary knowledge. Today's Androids and other small devices are embedded systems so the necessary hardware for flashing your solid state AND gate systems is part of the kernel or you just do it with a PC.

Comment: I write software that is programed into EEPROM daily.  I then execute that program.  The program runs and executes until I stop it.  I can also change the instructions at will by the way.  So you have technical problems with some your very first statement.  Plus you contradict yourself in your second sentence.  You state that Firmware is program that runs the system, that makes it software, somebody wrote firmware.  Firmware can also be updated. I also do it daily in my professional. You can also update the firmware of your Android phone that is done when a new version of Android is released.

Comment: Yes;  I know the different between EPROM and EEPROM.  Firmware isn't normally written EPROM anyways.

Comment: The most relevant part of this post is "My explanation is far from perfect".

Comment: "the programming language of C ... is ultimately what was invented to progress beyond binary."  C was far from the first high-order programming language.  (It was just the first "cool" one.)